# Can't encrypt with bitlocker: "the specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I have encrypted my primary drive with bitlocker (C:) and am looking to encrypt D:\ which is a stand-alone second hard drive. However, I get an error message in the "Bitlocker Drive Encryption (D:) dialogue:

`the specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted" when entering password`

Computer is not part of any domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [BitLocker Group Policy Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706521%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) :

> **Configure use of passwords on fixed data drives**
>
> This policy setting is used to require, allow, or deny the use of passwords with fixed data drives.
>
> When set to **Require complexity**, a connection to a domain
>   controller is necessary when BitLocker is enabled to validate the
>   complexity the password.
>
> When set to **Allow complexity**, a connection to a domain controller
>   will be attempted to validate that the complexity adheres to the rules
>   set by the policy. However, if no domain controllers are found, the
>   password will still be accepted regardless of the actual password
>   complexity and the drive will be encrypted by using that password as a
>   protector.
>
> When set to **Do not allow complexity**, no password complexity
>   validation will be done.

The procedure to verify this setting is as follows :

1. Click **Start**, type `gpedit.msc` in the Start Search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. The relevant BitLocker Group Policy settings can be found under :
   `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Fixed Data Drives`.
3. Double-click **Configure use of passwords for removable data drives**.
4. Ensure that it is set to either **Not configured** or **Disabled**.
   If set to **Enabled**, ensure that the drop-box below is set to either
   **Do not allow complexity** or **Allow complexity**.
5. Click **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange you got this message because as you have noted one would have expected to get the error on a machine that was connected to a domain. Still it's worth trying the following group policy setting even if just to rule it out.

Go to "Start -> Run -> gpedit.msc" to open the Local Group Policy Editor. Now in the editor navigate to Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Bitlocker Drive Encryption.

Open the policy setting called "Store Bitlocker recovery information in Active Directory Domain Services" and make sure that it is set to Not Configured.

If you read the description for that policy setting, it says that if you enable the policy and check the check-box for "Require Bitlocker backup to AD DS" then Bitlocker cannot be turned on unless the computer is 'connected to the domain and the backup of the Bitlocker recovery information to AD DS is successful'. So that could explain the cause of your issue.